# Can SSL using Blowfish cipher be considered strong enough?

Tags: aes, openvpn, blowfish

I use OpenVPN to connect to a public VPN. Sometimes I connect from my college campus (it's fully open to alumni) and when this happens I can only use TCP SSL because the college network has a security theater firewall that blocks everything except HTTP, TCP SSL and WhatsApp. My VPN provider only supports Blowfish cipher for TCP SSL connections; if I want to use AES-256, I have to use an UDP connection. [Wikipedia's entry on the Blowfish cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) says it can be considered secure and [this other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/which-ssl-tls-ciphers-can-be-considered-secure) mentions that any cipher more advanced than DES can be considered as "good enough", but the Wikipedia article mentions that there is a class of weak keys that are vulnerable to attacks.

Will I still be functionally secure (as in, it will take an awful lot of resources to eavesdrop my communications) if I use Blowfish instead of AES-256?

Answer (score 1):

Blowfish is secure enough for TLS/SSL but [AES is preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554526/comparison-of-des-triple-des-aes-blowfish-encryption-for-data). Especially 256, because 128 is still considered unbreakable and 256 is even more secure.